# grunt - doesn't give any output

Tags: gruntjs

I have installed grunt-cli,grunt(local),grunt-init. Below is the simple grunt file to minify javascript files in source folder.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    min: {
      dev: {
        src: 'calculator/*.js',
        dest: 'calculator.min.js'
      }
    }
  });
};
```

when I run grunt, it does nothing, nor it gives any message out. nor does grunt --help or grunt --version..none of them seem to say anything. but if I dont' have grunt.js file it does complain about the grunt file not existing and help gives the details..

Comment: I changed the file name gruntfile.js. it is responding now. But it says task min not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is add a task that then calls `min`. To get it to run by just using `grunt` you must call this task `default`. 
If you call it anything else (e.g. `development`, you must run `grunt development`)

You also need to make sure you have the necessary dependencies installed with `npm`. So `min` you probably want to minify JS with the gruntjs [`uglify` module](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify).

From the docs:

> Install this plugin with this command:
>
> `npm install
>   grunt-contrib-uglify --save-dev`
>
> Once the plugin has been installed,
>   it may be enabled inside your Gruntfile with this line of JavaScript:
>
> `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');`

For example, here are some snippets from one of my `Gruntfile.js`

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    // load all grunt tasks
    require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

    // configurable paths
    var yeomanConfig = {
        app: 'resources',
        dist: 'dist'
    };

    grunt.initConfig({
        yeoman: yeomanConfig,
        uglify: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/js/scripts.js': [
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>/js/lib/*.js'
                    ],
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/js/output.js': [
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>/js/*.js'
                    ],
                }
            }
        },
    });
    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        // 'jshint',
        // 'test',
        'uglify'
    ]);
```

The above sets up an `uglify` task and then the `grunt.registerTask('default'..` part calls `uglify` when I run grunt.

The above was generated and used as part of the [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) workflow.

Comment: so there is no more a default min,watch task with grunt..It has to be installed and loaded as grunt-contrib-[task]...and I have to register a default task, otherwise it would not run all the tasks as was shown in one video recorded jan 2013..so many changes. it looked nice with defaults..is there a way to have defaults...

Comment: Nop, it's all been separated now due to maintenance now there is no internal dependency if some plugin is getting updated outside grunt ecosystem.